# Neo4j doesn't support in Heroku?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, heroku, neo4j

I'm trying to deploy a Spring boot app with Neo4j database, but when I find addons in Heroku, I can't see it. How can I do to push my Neo4j database to Heroku?
Please help me! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This [news](https://docs.graphenedb.com/docs/shutdown-of-heroku-add-on) indicates that GrapheneDB shutting down its Heroku add-on.

I have not explored the direct path, as per the documentation you can still use

> You will still be able to use Heroku with GrapheneDB, just not as a Heroku add-on.

Comment: I have configured db url, username, password variables in Heroku, but I can't know to use in the next step. Could you help me, bro?

Comment: can you share sample project on github if you have

Comment: this is my project. It is a instagram clone. Thank you so much!
https://github.com/trantuananh1/my-moment/tree/master

Comment: GrapheneDB, now offer 14 day trial period with CC verification before creating project and database you can try that.